# vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices assigning 0 to variable GPU_Count

Tags: windows-10, driver, nvidia, vulkan

I installed the drivers for vulkan from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver).
And I installed the LunarG SDK, for testing i download NVIDIA Chopper Demo. I run it, but it says 0 Physical Devices found. I have two 2 GPU (Discrete and Integrated). What is the problem?

I know meaning of this vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices function assign GPU_Count variable 0. And this means i do not have any Vulkan capable GPU. **But i have**.

This my enviroment: NVIDIA GeForce 820M GPU, Intel Integrated Haswell GPU, Intel Core I5 CPU, Windows 10 OS.

Comment: did you update your driver? The default up to date driver may not have vulkan support enabled.

Comment: Whatever, i installed Ubuntu 16.04 and NVIDIA drivers. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out indirectly by ratchet freak, this typically occurs when a Vulkan compatible driver can't be found by the Vulkan loader (vulkan-1.so on Linux or vulkan-1.dll on Windows).